# Степени сравнения прилагательных

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, степени-прилагательных

От какого прилагательного образовано слово ***хуже?***

Answer (score 2):

> От какого прилагательного образовано слово ***хуже?***

***Хуже*** образовано от прилагательного ***худой*** со знач. *плохой, дурной, скверный.*

В настоящее время ***хуже*** квалифицируется как форма сравнительной степени прилагательных ***худой*** (в знач. *плохой, дурной*), ***плохой*** и наречий ***худо, плохо***.

Вот что пишет по поводу слова ***хуже*** Еськова в *"Кратком словаре трудностей русского языка":*

> Исторически форма ***хуже*** образована от ***худой;*** в современном
>   литературном языке ещё сохраняются фразеологические обороты, в которых
>   ***худой*** значит "плохой": *на худой конец, худая слава* и др. С другой стороны, от ***плохой*** существует форма ***плоше,***
>   стилистически сниженная (она употребляется в художественной речи с
>   особой стилистической целью). Получилось так, что ***худой***  —
>   "плохой" и форма ***плоше*** отошли на периферию литературного языка,
>   а "нормальное", нейтральное соотношение положительной и сравнительной
>   степени представлено в паре ***плохой  — хуже.***

Answer (score 0):

Это сравнительная степень прилагательного *плохой* (супплетивное формообразование): плохой — хуже — худший.

См. [ответ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=280176) Грамоты.ру.

Answer (score 0):

**Форма "хуже" образована от прилагательного "худой",** но при этом она является формой сравнительной степени для двух прилагательных: **плохой и худой.**

**Плохой/хуже** ― многозначное слово **нейтрального** стиля, супплетивное образование сравнительной степени.

**Худой** (в значении  "плохой, дурной")/**хуже** ― стиль **традиционно-народный**.